# Como obtengo los mismos resultados en mi query?

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de armar un query que me de toda la informacion de mis clientes con los contactos que tienen esos clientes, sin embargo, estuve probando y comparando y note, que cuando trato de "unir" la tabla clientes con la tabla contactos, me da menos clientes que buscando solo los clientes activos.

Para dar un ejemplo tengo este query:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE estado = 'A'
```

El cual me devuelve 462 resultados (esos son todos los clientes activos)

Pero cuando trato de unir con la tabla contactos me da menos, con este query:

```
SELECT c.id_cliente, c.nombre, c.direccion, c.ruc, c.correo, c.correo2, c.correo3, 
c.correo4, c.correo5, c.correo6, c.correo7, c.correo8, c.correo9, c.correo10, 
c.correo11, c.correo12, c.correo13, c.correo14, c.correo15, 
co.telefono as telefonoContacto, co.nombre as nombreContacto, 
co.apellido as apellidoContacto 
FROM clientes c, contactos co WHERE c.id_cliente = co.id_cliente 
AND c.estado = 'A'
```

Lamento que sea tan largo, pero fue la unica forma que se me ocurrio para tomar de ambas tablas, sin embargo este query me da 438 resultados, no 462, entonces queria saber si alguien de pronto me ayuda como mas podria hacer el query para que salgan los 462 activos.

De la tabla "clientes" necesito (los nombres son los que estan en la tabla):

- id_cliente
- nombre
- dirección
- ruc
- correo
- correo2
- correo3...hasta correo15

De "contactos" necesito (los nombres son los que estan en la tabla):

- nombre
- apellido
- telefono

También quiero aclarar que la tabla contactos tiene guardado el id_cliente al que pertenece cada contacto.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Quizá puedas utilizar LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Probe con esto: SELECT c.id_cliente, c.nombre, c.direccion, c.ruc, c.correo, c.correo2, c.correo3, c.correo4, c.correo5, c.correo6, c.correo7, c.correo8, c.correo9, c.correo10, c.correo11, c.correo12, c.correo13, c.correo14, c.correo15, co.telefono FROM clientes c LEFT JOIN contactos co ON c.id_cliente = co.id_cliente pero tampoco, este en cambio me da 489 resultados, algunos se estan repitiendo

Comment: en tu consulta te faltó añado la condición `WHERE estado = 'A'`

Comment: Okay ahora, la hice de esta manera:  SELECT c.id_cliente, c.nombre, c.direccion, c.ruc, c.correo, c.correo2, c.correo3, c.correo4, c.correo5, c.correo6, c.correo7, c.correo8, c.correo9, c.correo10, c.correo11, c.correo12, c.correo13, c.correo14, c.correo15, co.telefono, co.nombre as nombreContacto, co.apellido as apellidoContacto FROM clientes c LEFT JOIN contactos co ON c.id_cliente = co.id_cliente WHERE c.estado = 'A' sin embargo ahora me 464 resultados, osea un par se estan repitiendo..pero..creo que eso esta bien, son muchos para revisarlos todos

Comment: la relacion entre clientes y contactos es uno a uno? tener 15 campos de correo, salvo que des una explicacion muy pero muy logica, esta mal...

Comment: Eran 3 correos pero luego pidieron mas y mas correos y la unica forma que no dañara nada fue esa agregar mas campos de correo, en cuanto a la relacion de contactos, es un cliente puede tener varios contactos

Comment: Si tienes mas de un contacto por cliente, vas a generar varias filas por causa de los contactos. Si deseas mostrar un solo cliente con un solo contacto, deberias tener en la tabla de contactos algun campo 'contacto predeterminado' y filtrar contactos por este valor o decidir de alguna manera cual mostrar.